# Class of Algorithms where finding output of algorithm can be aided by output of same algorithm given a similar input

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory

Sorry for the confusing title, but I'm trying to find out if a certain algorithm or class of algorithms fits this description. Given an algorithm `A`, computing `A(x)` can be computionally easier if `A(g)` is known, where `g` is close to `x`, and it's easier the closer `g` gets to `x`. So also, the amount of computation `A` has to do grows with respect to the size of the input.

You would also have to be able to calculate the output of `A(x)` given `A(g)`, `x-g`, `A(x-g)`. Does `A` exist for anything other than trivial artithemtic, and if so, is there an entire class of algorithms which `A` belongs to?

Comment: Welcome to CS.SE!  Can you edit the question to provide any context about your motivation for asking or how you'll use answers or to narrow down the question?  This might help us provide answers that are more likely to be useful to you.  I think there are many such algorithms (e.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_problem_(algorithms)), so it's hard to select just one.

Comment: It seems that whenever you say *algorithm*, you really mean *computational problem* or *function*.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I agreee; those terms are what I'm trying to say

Comment: What's the difference with *dynamic programming*?

Comment: Although the concept of _dynamic programming_ is related, you seem to be describing _recursive_ algorithms in general, since those algorithms will be faster if you have precomputed a 'close' value (depending on the definition of 'close'). As far as I know, all algorithms that compute computable functions can be described using recursion, so this is a very general class. So, I think you have to be more precise about your input domains (just integers, or something else?) and what 'close' means on the input.

Answer (score 1):

It can be algorithms which use initial guess, for example algorithms for finding roots and local minimums/maximum like Newton's method and gradient descend. Here `g` and `x` are functions, and `g` is close to `x` means that they have roots or local minimums/maximums in similar locations, so taking `A(g)` as initial guess, algorithm can converge faster to `A(x)`.

Answer (score 1):

In complexity theory, a problem $A$ is called *self-reducible*, if a $A(x)$ can be computed easily when given the solutions to one or more subproblems $A(x')$ for inputs with $|x'| < |x|$ for free. What "easily" means depends on the context, in most cases it means "in polynomial time" in the context where $A$ is $\mathsf{NP}$-complete.

The standard example is $SAT$, where the problem of satisfiability of a formula $\varphi$ reduces to the same problem for the two formulas $\varphi[x:=0]$ and $\varphi[x:=1]$, which are smaller than $\varphi$ after simpification.